# Cannot curl Kubernetes (EKS) pod from another node

Tags: kubernetes, containers, amazon-eks

got 2 EKS clusters, each cluster has 1 nodes, failing to curl between the 2 nodes. i can easily curl between 2 pods in the same node, but when trying to curl the same pod from another node, the request hangs untill timeout.

created a service of type NodePort:

```
`apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: geth-beacon-chain-testnet
  name: rpc-json-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - name: "j"
      port: 8545
      targetPort: 8545
      nodePort: 30003
  selector:
    app: geth-beacon-chain-testnet
`
```

running `kubectl get services -o wide`:

```
`NAME                    TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                                                                    AGE   SELECTOR
rpc-json-service        NodePort    10.100.8.162     <none>        8545:30003/TCP                                              14d   app=geth-beacon-chain-testnet`
```

both nodes are in the same subnets, trying to curl to `10.100.8.162:30003` from the other node results in timeout.

i have checked coredns, kube-proxy etc and all other k8s system related pods and all seem to be running without issues

i have tried testing in various configurations of NodePort services, i tried setting up the NodePort on the opposite node and try to access that one, all attempts resulted in timeout of the curl request

Comment: Have you checked the security groups on the two nodes?

Comment: yes, for testing sake i allowed all ips in the inbound section, still times out

Comment: Try to run Reachability Analyzer to check where the communication between the two instance is broken: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/reachability/what-is-reachability-analyzer.html<br/>
Anyway you should enable, in Security Groups, the outbound of the curling instance and the inbound of the curled one.